# Why does importing a module cause the module to run when calling it from site-packages, but not when I call it locally?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I made a package in python using distutils in this sort of fashion:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from distutils.core import setup

setup(name='mypackage4.py',
    version='1.0',
    description='Description',
packages=['mypackage4']
)
```

setup.py then installs it to my python2.7/site-packages directory.

When I run

```
import mypackage4
```

it tries to run the .py files in the mypackage4 directory. The directory contains python files which contain functions (def commands). All I want to do is make the functions available for use, not to run directly on import.

If however, I do

```
cd python2.7/site-packages
```

and then do the import so it picks up mypackage4 locally, it imports without running anything, so then I can access the functions from the python command line in the normal way.

Why does python seem to run the functions when the package is not in the local directory, but not run the functions when the package is in the local directory?

Secondly, I read about placing a

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
else:
    <define functions here>
```

command in my .py files to prevent them from running, but then surely it doesn't run the functions, so how does it know about them?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

ps, (in case this helps) In my package directory I have an `__init__.py` file to tell python which files to import

```
__all__ = [
    'pyfile1',
    'pyfile2',
    'pyfile3',
]
```

Comment: Is it possible that there is another `mypackage4.py` file that gets imported, either locally or globally, when you perform the import while in another directory? An easy way to tell is to print out the package's `__file__` attribute after importing in both scenarios.

Comment: You seem to be right! I found it was referencing an old version of mypackage4 in the $PYTHONPATH before searching in site-packages. I deleted the version in $PYTHONPATH and now it works. I'm not sure why the older version ran the functions while the newer version imports nicely without running them (I should have kept a spare copy to study the former, before deleting). But the problem seems to be solved now. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 3):

> The directory contains python files which contain functions (def commands). All I want to do is make the functions available for use, not to run directly on import.

The `def` statements are code, that has to get run, or the functions don't get defined. Python *always* runs your code when you import a module or package. Function, class, and global variable/constant definitions are code, just like anything else.

The functions don't get *called* unless you write code to call them. But if you do write such code, it gets run. There's no special state where `def foo(i): print(i)` happens, but `foo(3)` does not; all of your code gets run.

Sometimes, you want to write a module that can be imported by other code, but can also be run as a script. (Or you may just want the module to run its tests when executed as a script.) That's where the `__main__` idiom comes in.

You've got the idiom a little bit wrong—or, rather, you're putting an uncommon case in front of the typical one. Usually, you do something like this:

```
def foo(f):
    blahblah(f)

def bar(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        foo(f)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
        bar(arg)
```

When you import the module, the `foo` and `bar` definitions get executed, so the importing code can do `qux.bar(fname)`, but the stuff inside the `if` statement does not get executed (because `__name__ != '__main__'` for an imported module). When you run the module as a script, that stuff *does* get executed (because `__name__ == '__main__'`). So, you can do `./qux.py myfile.txt` (or `C:\Python33\Python.exe .\qux.py myfile.txt`, or whatever) and it'll foo the heck out of myfile.txt for you.

You rarely need to put anything in an `else` block for the `if __name__ == '__main__'`.

But rarely isn't never. Sometimes you have definitions that are needed to use the module as a module, but not needed to run it as a script. If compiling those definitions takes a long time (e.g., because the module precomputes a 100000-element `dict` to speed up access later), you don't want to do that every time you run the script. So, those definitions would go into the `else` block.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I really appreciate you taking the time to write a detailed reply and it's helpful for my understanding of how this works (I didn't downvote!). But I still don't understand why it seems to work differently, when called from a local directory or called from site-packages.

Comment: @Tetsuo: Yeah, I'm only answering about 2/3rds of your problem here. I have to go now, but I'll check back tomorrow, and if nobody's looked into the site-packages part I'll take a look. Meanwhile, it might help if you posted your code somewhere—or, better, created a stripped-down minimal example that exhibits the behavior you're interested in—so someone can write a concrete answer instead of a bunch of abstractions.

Comment: As I wrote in my reply to Nisan.H's comment, it seems to have been referencing an older version of mypackage4 (apparently it searches in $PYTHONPATH before site-packages). Quite why the $PYTHONPATH version produced the "running" results while the site-packages version imports nicely without generating output, I'm not sure, but at least it's working, and I learned a lot from both of you. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Tetsuo you're welcome. We've all been there before (how else would we ourselves have learned?)